# How to add a button to the main toolbar in Eclipse programmatically

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I've a question. I cannot find the way, how to add buttons to main toolbar programmatically. My problem is, that I've the task to dynamically (based on XML configuration file) build menus and toolbar. I found how to add a menu item programmatically, but not toolbar button.

Tutorials mostly show how to create buttons and menus using plugin descriptor (plugin.xml), but not how to do it programatically. It seems, that it is out of bounds of Eclipse plugin philosophy.

I've just found [this](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/202213/):

> There might be layout problems with this approach. I also don't
>   believe the framework will try and re-create your dynamic item except
>   at random toolbarmanager updates. With Menus they can be updated on an
>   SWT.Show event, which is why CompoundContributionItem only applies to
>   Menus.

What shall I do? Can I say *Sorry, there is no way to build toolbar dynamically. I can do it just for menus*? Collegue says, that it must be possible, but he does neither know how.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to be able to create main toolbar entries programmatically is in an RCP app, where you supply the `ActionBarAdvisor` for the workbench window.  This isn't dynamic, however, just called on window creation.

Another way to do it would be to use `org.eclipse.ui.menus` and contribute `org.eclipse.ui.menus.ExtensionContributionFactory`.  It also works only on workbench window creation (not really dynamic), but you could read your own XML and provide IContributionItems for the main menu or toolbar.

How dynamic are you trying to be?  Most solutions work well on startup/window creation.

PW

Comment: I need to create menus and toolbars at the start or after the workspace has been switched.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you try to do something programmatically in Eclipse that is normally done through plugin definitions you are walking on thin ice. I've tried it on a few occasions and it rarely ended up being easy or good.

Instead, think of what it is that you only know at runtime and need to be able to change on the fly. Is it the name or icon of the button? That can be changed at runtime. 
Take a look at [runtime commands](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCommandsAdvanced/article.html), they can be confusing to define properly, but with them you can for example create buttons that are only visible if a condition is active. That condition could be set at runtime.

Comment: I've persuaded in last time, that this solution can be hardly implemented. Each menu item shall execute some external command. The easiest way is to generate `plugin.xml` according to the structure. Each item has an ID and is handled by the same action class. The class executes proper command. Commands will be defined in file `command.properties`. Each line contains pair _itemId-command_. The plugin will be installed in `.plugins` directory of the workspace. Instances will differ only in `plugin.xml` and `command.properties`. When the workspace is being switched, new configuration is loaded.